# How to effectively handle session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I have one web site with multiple accounts like staff, end user and admin.

However I am creating each session while the user is logged into their account.

```
if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            string type_name="";
            int returnValue = DatabaseHelper.GetLogin(txtusername.Text.Trim(), txtpassword.Text.Trim(), out type_name);
            if (returnValue == 1)
            {
                if (chk_remember.Checked == true)
                {
                    if (type_name.Trim()=="Admin")
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = txtusername.Text;
                        Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = txtpassword.Text;
                        Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                        Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                        Session["username"] = txtusername.Text.Trim();
                        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin_Landing_page.aspx");
                    }
                    else if (type_name.Trim()=="User")
                    {
                        Response.Cookies["UName"].Value = txtusername.Text;
                        Response.Cookies["PWD"].Value = txtpassword.Text;
                        Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                        Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2);
                        Session["username"] = txtusername.Text.Trim();
                        Response.Redirect("~/EndUser/myhome.aspx");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Cookies["UName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    Response.Cookies["PWD"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
                    if (type_name.Trim()== "Admin")
                    {
                        Session["username"] = txtusername.Text.Trim();
                        Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Admin_Landing_page.aspx");
                    }
                    else if (type_name.Trim()== "User")
                    {
                        Session["username"] = txtusername.Text.Trim();
                        Response.Redirect("~/EndUser/myhome.aspx");
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (returnValue == -1)
            {
                ltr_error.Text = "Authentication failed..contact administrator";
            }
            else
            {
                ltr_error.Text = "Invalid username or password";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here, sessions are created but how I handle them for long time as possible in ASP.NET timeout? Is that way to handle them with global.asax file?

Also, how do I redirect the user to login page if no session found in application?

**-------------------------------------Updated----------------------------------------**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class WebUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
        {
            if (this.Page.User != null && this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
        }    
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? I'm thinking it is either "How do I create a session?", "Can I increase the session timeout period?" or "How do I deal with a timed out session?"

Comment: how can i increase session time out and how do i deal with a timed out session.

Comment: Ahmed's answer, below, is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session by default lasts for 20 mins - depending on the setting in IIS and also the web.config.
if session is expires, the Session_End event in the global.asax gets fired. from there, you cannot exactly redirect and would not be the right place to redirect anyway.

you should create a user control for example, which is on every page or even better a master page from which all pages derive from, then you can check on every request if Session is empty. if so, redirect to the logon page.

I have done this many times and works a treat.

I have this on a prerender event in a user control:

```
if (Context.Session != null && Context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                if (this.Page.User != null && this.Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
                }
            }
```

Comment: ya i added user control and writes your method in Pre_Render event. how i implement on master page. please see my updated question.

Comment: the masterpage was a suggestion. just place the control on pages you want to check for session state ending/new and you are done. or if you have a master page where all pages derive from, then plonk the control on the master page...job done.

Comment: is that like this <%@ Reference Control="~/WebUserControl.ascx"  %>

Comment: yes - to add the user control to the page. but that is just referencing it. you need to add the actual instance of the control, like how you would add an instance of say, a button control.

Comment: seems you don't know much about ASP.NET? go to www.asp.net and learn how to make simple ASP.NET apps - there are samples there :). do you know what a user control is? do you know how to add a button to a webpage? if you do - you do the same with the user control when you reference it in the ASPX

Comment: ok i understand just add control like button in WeUserControl. after that in master page just add this line <%@ Register Src="~/WebUserControl.ascx" TagName="ButtonUserControl" TagPrefix="uc1"%> and after that place uc1:ButtonUserControl="ButtonUserControl1" runat="server" /> line between form tag.

Comment: set visibility to true otherwise the control will not render and you will not get the behavior you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: how ever i don't want to display this button to user so can i manually set visibilty false when i put <uc1:ButtonUserControl ID="ButtonUserControl" runat="server" Visible="false"/> or any other control idea..

Comment: the control needs to be visible otherwise you will NOT get the behavior I am describing to you and the behavior you want. you should NOT place anything else inside the usercontrol which checks the session and redirects to the logon page if session has ended